# I struggle a lot to apply loop in dataframe, How can I improve this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for loop in dataframe
I tried this can anyone help me with the correct answer

```
for i in df['name']:
    if df['name'] = 'Amit':
        print('yes Amit')
    else:
        df['name'] = 'not Amit'
```

| name | age | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amit | 45 | Pune |
| Ajay | 25 | Pune |

Comment: The question is wrong. Never ask: "How to apply a loop on a `dataframe`?". 
Ask: "How *not* to apply a loop on a `dataframe`?"

Comment: First of all `=` is assignment, while `==` is comparison. Then the main advantage of a DF is not to use loop

Comment: Do you want to `print` or to change the values of the DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is your dataframe but this :

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['name'] == 'Amit':
        df.loc[i, 'name'] = 'yes Amit'
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'name'] = 'not Amit'
```

Might do what you want.

Comment: Well he can also do this :

df.loc[df['name'] == 'Amit', 'name'].apply(lambda x: print('yes Amit') if x == 'Amit' else print('not Amit'))

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your dataframe is:

```
df_data = {
     'name' : ['Amit','Peter','Carl','Mary','Amit','Hank','Ali'],
     'age': [45,34,23,56,21,23,45]
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    name  age
0   Amit   45
1  Peter   34
2   Carl   23
3   Mary   56
4   Amit   21
5   Hank   23
6    Ali   45
```

Basically, if you want to run a 'loop', you should do something like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if df['name'][index] == 'Amit':
    print('yes Amit')
  else:
    print('not Amit')
```

Output:

```
yes Amit
not Amit
not Amit
not Amit
yes Amit
not Amit
not Amit
```

But usually it is better NOT to do the "loop", and there are always more optimized methods!

```
df['name'].apply(lambda x: 'yes Amit' if x == 'Amit' else 'not Amit')
```

Output:

```
0    yes Amit
1    not Amit
2    not Amit
3    not Amit
4    yes Amit
5    not Amit
6    not Amit
```

And also:

```
df['Y/N'] = df['name'] == 'Amit'
```

Output:

```
    name  age    Y/N
0   Amit   45   True
1  Peter   34  False
2   Carl   23  False
3   Mary   56  False
4   Amit   21   True
5   Hank   23  False
6    Ali   45  False
```

Also take a look at: [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)